# Iframe/ Youtube scrolltop position fixed

Tags: jquery, html, wordpress, embed, scrolltop

Hi all looked all over but can't find anybody with the same problem or maybe I'm searching on the wrong description. It comes down to this. I am working on this site http://lennyryan.com/test/ it has a menu under the header wich sticks on top. All this works fine except for when I embed a youtube video.Than it screws up it seems that it changed all the position: fixed divs to relative. To be honest I'm not really sure what it does. Would be really helpful if somebody could just help me why it screws up...

You can see the website here http://lennyryan.com/test/

*Edit it does work in Firefox but it has problems in Safari and Chrome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Saw some people on the internet with the same kind of question and I found the answer myself so I thought I would post it. It is something really stupid but unexpected so kind of hard to find out. There is a negative z-index in your css somewhere wich gives all kind of rendering problems when the youtube video is embeded.So pretty dumb from my part still a really weird result that it would copy divs etc..